# How to fix: spawner not spawning in zombies

Tags: lua, roblox

I am making a game right now and I have a problem with one of the scripts that spawn in zombies. I'm not sure what went wrong, but I feel like as if there is nothing wrong going on with my code. Here is it, any help is appreciated. Maybe an alternate solution to spawning the zombies will help.

```
local NPC = game.ReplicatedStorage.Trollanoid
local spawner = script.Parent
local spawneron = false
game.ReplicatedStorage.Values.gameInProgress.Changed:Connect(function()
    if game.ReplicatedStorage.Values:FindFirstChild("gameInProgress").Value == true then
        if game.ReplicatedStorage.Values:FindFirstChild("zombiesRemaining").Value > 0 then  
            spawneron = true
        end
    end
end)

while spawneron == true do
    local Clone = NPC:Clone()
    Clone.UpperTorso.CFrame = spawner.CFrame
    Clone.Parent = workspace
    game.ReplicatedStorage.Values:FindFirstChild("zombiesRemaining").Value =                     
game.ReplicatedStorage.Values:FindFirstChild("zombiesRemaining").Value - 1
    wait(3)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what is happening in your script :

1. declare some variables
2. connect to a signal
3. check if `spawneron == true`? no, skip loop
4. done

When the signal fires and you set `spawneron` to true, your code does not re-enter and activate the while-loop. To make it do that, just move your loop inside a function, and call that function when the signal fires.

```
local NPC = game.ReplicatedStorage.Trollanoid
local gameInProgress = game.ReplicatedStorage.Values.gameInProgress
local zombiesRemaining = game.ReplicatedStorage.Values.zombiesRemaining
local spawner = script.Parent

local function spawnZombies()
    while zombiesRemaining.Value > 0 do
        local Clone = NPC:Clone()
        Clone:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(spawner.CFrame)
        Clone.Parent = workspace
        zombiesRemaining.Value = zombiesRemaining.Value - 1
        wait(3)
    end
end

gameInProgress.Changed:Connect(function(newValue)
    if newValue == true then
        if zombiesRemaining.Value > 0 then  
            spawnZombies()
        end
    end
end)
```

Comment: It works!


But it only spawns one. How to fix?

Comment: My code assumes that zombiesRemaining is the total number to spawn. So, maybe set `game.ReplicatedStorage.Values.zombiesRemaining` to a larger number? If it is meant to be a counter of how many zombies are in the round in total, then there needs to be a different exit condition